# Looking for help. view.backgroundColor

Tags: swift, button, background-color

I'm new to swift programming and having trouble solving this project. I need to make the button background change color every time it is clicked, I've managed to solve it if it's only two colors but not more than that. Any help is appreciated. This is what I managed to come up with using two colors.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var lightOn = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        lightOn.toggle()
        updateUI()
    }
    func updateUI() {
        if lightOn {
            view.backgroundColor = .orange
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an array of `UIColor` and use a `Int` index that will increase on button tap?

Comment: Do u want a random color?

Comment: Yes, aheze, any three random colors.

Answer (score 1):

You're halfway there - you have a button tap executing `updateUI`. Truth is, you shouldn't even need a variable called `lightOn`. Instead of an `if` statement, try a `switch`:

```
switch view.backgroundColor {
case UIColor.orange:
    view.backgroundColor = .red
case UIColor.red:
    view.backgroundColor = .green
case UIColor.green:
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
default:
    break
}
```

This will cycle from orange to red to blue. Add in colors as desired. A few notes:

- Unless you define the colors in an `enum`, you'll get a compiler error without this `default`. If you do define the colors you want, then all you need is to *fully* put each color defined in the switch statement. This really is good coding - since you now won't build without it.
- Be careful to initialize the view color to something defined specifically in the switch statement.
- Now, if you need to go from... say (1) red to green back to (2) red to blue back to (3) red to orange... basically, alternating from "off" to "on" where "on" cycles to a different color, yes, by all means *use* `lightOn` *and* move this switch statement aside the `if` statement you posted, setting it like you have.

Comment: If use a switch can I make the switch fill the whole screen? Because I just want the button  to fill the whole screen in an iPhone and remove the lettering "button" so the whole screen would turn that said color when it is tapped but in reality your tapping the button.

Comment: I think. I actually was posting code that would only change the button - but your code worked with the view. :-) Simply work with the button background color instead of the view. All a switch statement really is is a *much* more readable code than if and nested if else. (Also, the Swift complier offers much more help when building.

Comment: You need a case for .blue.  Otherwise it will get stuck as blue.  You could have it circle back to .red.

Comment: @Swiftnoob, by `switch` @dfd means a switch statement, not a `UISwitch`. A switch statement is like an extended if-else. A `UISwitch` is the toggle on/off user interface element.

Comment: Thanks, ahaze, I'll get the hang of it one day. @dfd- This might be a dumb question but where do I place the enumeration? I've looked at google and I think this would work enum ColorName: String { case red, blue, green }. I've compiled with the switch command inside the if statement but it won't change color when the button is pressed, I'll keep working on it. Thanks